# Adding Parameters to Wordpress PHP Function

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, function

Please forgive me if my verbiage is incorrect!

I have a working function that outputs a font-awesome icon based on a post's category. I'm looking to expand the function so I can also specify the size within my call, based on an array within the function.

Here's the working code

```
<?php echo category_icon(); ?> -- html output is <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>)
```

And I'm looking to achieve the following...

```
<?php echo category_icon($icon_size); ?>  --output would be <i class="fa fa-desktop$icon_size"></i>)
```

And here is my current function

```
function category_icon($icon_size){
    $build_icon_cat = get_the_category();
    $choose_icon = $build_icon_cat[0]->cat_ID;

            // chooses icon by category
            if ($choose_icon == 19) $build_icon_dos = 'fa fa-desktop';
             elseif ($choose_icon == 15) $build_icon_dos = '<i class="fa fa-cog';

    //-------size array
$icon_size = array(
    '' => '',
    '1' => ' fa-lg',
    '2' => ' fa-2x',
    '3' => ' fa-3x',
    '4' => ' fa-4x',
    '5' => ' fa-5x',
  );

//variables for building
        $build_icon_uno = '<i class="';
        $build_icon_cuatro = '"></i>';
        $display_category_icon = $build_icon_uno . $build_icon_dos . $icon_size . $build_icon_cuatro;

return $display_category_icon;
```

Comment: You have `$icon_size` as an argument, and then you're redeclaring it as an array. Change the name of the array to something like `$icon_array`, and then you can retrieve a size like so: `$icon_array[$icon_size]`, where `$icon_size` is simply a matching index (ie: '', '1', '2'...)

Comment: After days of searching it works perfectly.. thank you!

Comment: Posting as an answer, then. Please accept when you're able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `$icon_size` set as an argument, and then you're redeclaring it as an array. Change the name of the array to something like `$icon_array`, and then you can retrieve a size like so: `$icon_array[$icon_size]`, where `$icon_size` is simply a matching index (ie: '', '1', '2'...).

You may also want to consider implementing some basic validation using [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), as well as some default sizing.

Comment: Created this function example for general learning so it's dumbed down as much as possible. I guess next on the agenda is learning isset. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to maiorano84 for providing the insight. Here is the working code.

Callback on index.php

```
<?php echo category_icon('5'); ?>
```

Working function

```
function category_icon($icon_size){
    $build_icon_cat = get_the_category();
    $choose_icon = $build_icon_cat[0]->cat_ID;

            // chooses icon by category
            if ($choose_icon == 19) $build_icon_dos = 'fa fa-desktop';
             elseif ($choose_icon == 15) $build_icon_dos = '<i class="fa fa-cog';

    //-------size array
$icon_array = array(
    '' => '',
    '1' => ' fa-lg',
    '2' => ' fa-2x',
    '3' => ' fa-3x',
    '4' => ' fa-4x',
    '5' => ' fa-5x',
  );

//variables for building
        $build_icon_uno = '<i class="';
        $build_icon_cuatro = '"></i>';
        $display_category_icon = $build_icon_uno . $build_icon_dos . $icon_array[$icon_size] . $build_icon_cuatro;

return $display_category_icon;
}
```